# Would a clustered index improve performance, without using its column in selects?

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

I have a set of data with a natural primary key. I have to import that data into a SQL Server database. The PK is unique and is fixed to 20 characters, but is not ever increasing. So it would be a bad idea to use it as clustered index due to fragmentation, right? The data would be accessed only through that PK and range queries won't occur.

I thought about, just to create a table as a heap with a non-clustered index on that PK.

So if I run something like this:

```
select * from table where pk = something
```

RID look-ups would occur for every select.

But what would happen if I add an int identity column to that table and create a clustered index on it? Would I benefit from that performance-wise, even if I never use that new column in any select statements?

My guess is, that it would still have a heap like structure, because the ordering would solely depend on, in which order I insert the data. The only thing that would change is, that the clustered index would be used for look-ups, which wouldn't be noticeably faster, right?

Comment: [Which is faster](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)? Dont you have the tools to try it out yourself and monitor the performance?

Comment: NO, if you don't use the indexed column then it will perform a culstered index scan which is equivalent to full table scan.

Comment: @Rahul: actually, I don't think this statement of yours is correct. Since the clustering key actually **physically** orders the data by its key, chances are that the data pages will be arranged in a more "clustered" fashion and thus a clustered index scan (across all data pages in a clustered index) is typically faster than a very "random" table scan across a heap where the pages are spread out everywhere on disk ....

Comment: Also, if you read [Kim Tripp's The Clustered Index Debate continues...](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) blog post, you'll see that every other operation (including deletes!) is typically **faster** in a clustered environment. Therefore, I generally recommend to **always** use a **good** clustering key (narrow, static, unique, ever-increasing)

Comment: @marc_s, Thanks for the comment and really good info for me but question is: `typically faster` means is the speed measurable> My idea was that, the speed you are talking about is negligible.

Comment: @Rahul: probably depends on so many factors - can't really say. You'd have to actually use the concrete scenario and see what the difference is.